# Logged changes to an audit log

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a little app and want to keep a human-readable audit log of any changes to the database (so intentionally avoiding tools which log changes as written to the database)

The code below works but it is not at all elegant.  Can you come up wiht a more elegant way to implement this?

```
def auditdiff(set1, set2):
    new = set(set1.items())
    old = set(session[set2].items())
    diffset = dict(old ^ new) # holds what has changed
    m = {}
    for d in diffset:
        for pair in old:
            if pair[0] == d:
                m[d + " OLD"] =  pair[1]

        for pair in new:
            if pair[0] == d:
                m[d + " NEW"] = pair[1]
    return(m)
```

Here are examples of the variables as caught by the debugger:

set1:  (old values)

```
<class 'dict'>: {'date': '2019-04-25', 'student_id': None, 'booking_id': '', 'key': '', 'status': 'ATTEND', 'note': 'this is a changed note', 'charge': False}
```

set2:  (new values)

```
<class 'set'>: {('date', '2019-04-25'), ('note', 'this is a note'), ('student_id', None), ('charge', False), ('key', ''), ('status', 'ATTEND'), ('booking_id', '')}
```

diffset:  (difference)

```
<class 'dict'>: {'note': 'this is a changed note'}
```

m: (old and new changed values)

```
<class 'dict'>: {'note OLD': 'this is a note', 'note NEW': 'this is a changed note'}
```

Kind regards

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? `auditdiff` here accepts two dictionaries and generates 4-tuples describing changes:

- the first value is the key affected
- the second value is a verb `added`/`removed`/`changed`
- the third value is the old value, if any
- the fourth value is the new value, if any

The changes are always emitted in lexicographical key order.

```
def auditdiff(d1, d2):
    for key in sorted(set(d1) | set(d2)):
        if key in d1 and key not in d2:
            yield (key, "removed", d1[key], None)
        elif key in d2 and key not in d1:
            yield (key, "added", None, d2[key])
        elif d1[key] != d2[key]:
            yield (key, "changed", d1[key], d2[key])


d1 = {
    "date": "2019-04-25",
    "student_id": None,
    "booking_id": "",
    "key": "",
    "status": "ATTEND",
    "note": "this is a changed note",
    "charge": False,
    "greeting": "hello",  # this was added c.f. the original demo data
}
d2 = {
    "charge": False,
    "note": "this is a note",
    "key": "",
    "date": "2019-04-25",
    "student_id": None,
    "status": "ATTEND",
    "booking_id": "",
    "hello": "world",  # this was added c.f. the original demo data
}


for difference in auditdiff(d1, d2):
    print(difference)
```

outputs

```py
('greeting', 'removed', 'hello', None)
('hello', 'added', None, 'world')
('note', 'changed', 'this is a changed note', 'this is a note')
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat whimsical solution:

```
d1 = {
    "date": "2019-04-25",
    "student_id": None,
    "booking_id": "",
    "key": "",
    "status": "ATTEND",
    "note": "this is a changed note",
    "charge": False,
    "greeting": "hello",  # this was added c.f. the original demo data
}
d2 = {
    "charge": False,
    "note": "this is a note",
    "key": "",
    "date": "2019-04-25",
    "student_id": None,
    "status": "ATTEND",
    "booking_id": "",
    "hello": "world",  # this was added c.f. the original demo data
}

class LabeledTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, t, label):
        result = super().__new__(cls, t)
        result.label = label
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label + super().__repr__()


def labeled_set(d, name):
    return {LabeledTuple(t, name) for t in d.items()}


print(sorted(labeled_set(d1, "OLD") ^ labeled_set(d2, "NEW")))
# [OLD('greeting', 'hello'), NEW('hello', 'world'), OLD('note', 'this is a changed note'), NEW('note', 'this is a note')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on yours. It assumes that both dictionaries have the same keys.

```
d1 = {
    "date": "2019-04-25",
    "student_id": None,
    "booking_id": "",
    "key": "",
    "status": "ATTEND",
    "note": "this is a changed note",
    "charge": False,
}
d2 = {
    "charge": False,
    "note": "this is a note",
    "key": "",
    "date": "2019-04-25",
    "student_id": None,
    "status": "ATTEND",
    "booking_id": "",
}

diffset = dict(set(d1.items()) ^ set(d2.items()))  # holds what has changed

m = {}
for key in diffset:
    m[key + " OLD"] = d1[key]
    m[key + " NEW"] = d2[key]

print(m)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it'll handle added or removed keys correctly, though.